# Put each item printed into a list

Tags: python

I have a script that finds usernames and saves it to a file. I want to convert the usernames in accounts.txt to a list. I am unsure how to do this... Does anyone know how to help?

accounts.txt

```
@example1
@example2
@example3
@example4
@example5
@example6
```

What I want my program to create from accounts.txt:

```
['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5', 'example6']
```

Comment: each stripped line of the file should be an element of the list. What did you try?

Comment: I am not sure where to start... @DirtyBit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file using `readlines()` and then strip each line using list-comprehension:

```
with open("accounts.txt") as fileObj:
    content = fileObj.readlines()

# getting rid of the empty lines
file_data = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

Comment: This does not do anything. Essentially, I want it to print out the list

Comment: @kkkasla just `print(file_data)`?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this?

```
my_list = []

with open("accounts.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        my_list.extend(line.split())
my_list = [s[1:] for s in my_list]


print(my_list)
```

will print this: `['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5', 'example6']`

Answer (score 0):

You have to read each line and remove first `@' character and add in the list.
Try below code

```py
with open("accounts.txt","r") as f:
    print([a[1:].strip() for a in f])
```

**Output**

```
['example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5', 'example6']
```